# Google Sheets, one distinct cell to calculate multiple values for multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I'll try my best to explain the issue,

So I have created a spreadsheet which calculates my working hours, breaks, fortnightly pay and fortnightly tax automatically.

The problem I am having is, I need to copy/paste the fortnight schedule/listing every fortnight, which is fine because everything still works perfectly, except the tax section. No matter how much extra I earn the second fortnight, it will still reference the first fortnight and apply the same tax.

> **SAMPLE SHEET**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kEBNssfw_hSoJ8DQZ6oSym7PHf5tJYEgNnaW3zYijbo/edit?usp=sharing

> **explained in dot points first, just as an example:**

- **sheet1!a2** = fortnight1 earnings
- **sheet1!a16** = fortnight2 earnings
- **sheet1!a31** = fortnight3 earnings

  - **Sheet2!a5** = referenced earnings from **a2,a16,a31**
  - **Sheet2!b5** = tax calculator, calculates tax separately for all references in **Sheet2!a5**
  - **Sheet1!b2** = fortnight1 calulated tax from **sheet2!b5** for **sheet1!a2**
  - **Sheet1!b16** = fortnight2 calulated tax from **sheet2!b5** for **sheet1!a16**
  - **Sheet1!b31** = fortnight3 calulated tax from **sheet2!b5** for **sheet1!a31**

*This is essentially what I'm trying to achieve.*

> **Basically...**

I want the tax for **a2,a16** and **a31** earnings to be calculated from the the same sell in **sheet2 (cell b5)**. I don
t want to make duplicates of the calculator in **sheet2** for each fortnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **B2** type:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A2)=FALSE,"-",VLOOKUP(A2,'Fortnight Tax'!$A$6:$B$15,2))
```

And then copy paste it in **B16**,**B31** and etc. If you copy the cell instead of the formula, it will adjust to **A16**,**A31** etc.

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16Rb6cSTSFQQU3korETQ4c5PjyBiSVVfeA5QaONyLKZs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you sir, you just saved me a lot of messing around! It works great!